# Проблема разделения мест вывода ссылок и обрабатывающих компонентов

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Я начинающий в React.js и сразу прошу писать только , если есть четкий ответ, а не лить воду, я пока еще не использую webpack, redux и так далее, чистый reqct.js . Скорее всего это вопрос для тех, кто уже написал несколько одностраничных приложений на React.js .

Появилась следующая проблема : при организации ссылок, они должны помещаться внутрь < Router> или компонент, который их в него выведет, не важно. Но компоненты, которые отвечают за обработку перехода по ссылкам (< Route> )  тоже должны находится внутри < Router> :

```
//какой-то код до этого

<Router>
   <Link to='какой-то путь'> Текст </Link>
   <Link to='какой-то путь'> Текст </Link>

   <Route path='какой-то путь' component={компонент обработки}/>
   <Route path='какой-то путь' component={компонент обработки}/>
</Router>
```

Вот и получается, если я хочу вывести в разные части приложения ссылки и их руты, то они будут находится в разных роутерах и тогда обработка не работает, они должны находится в общем.

Не ужели нет другого способа это организовать, кроме как пихать эти части приложения, в которых я хочу вывести ссылки и компоненты обработки в общее дерево компонентов , что бы в итоге они были в одном роутере, нельзя просто вывести их в разных местах, разными компонентами без объединения или наследования. Может так просто не принято подходить к архитектуре, прошу пролить на это свет разработчиков с опытом, заранее спасибо.

Comment: _они должны помещаться внутрь < Router> или компонент, который их в него выведет, не важно_  - почему вы так решили?

Comment: Router должен обрамлять всё ваше приложение, и проблема решена

Comment: Хорошо, я могу все приложение вложить в Router , но на сколько такой подход к архитектуре считается правильным или приемлемым ?

Comment: считается правильным кем?

Comment: в общем надо вложить, он же передаёт контекст через всё приложение

Comment: спасибо большое